# How can I use wildcards in `aws-cli ec2` commands?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I have some EC2 instances. I want to use the `ec2 describe-instances` command to get a list of instances based on a specific value of a tag.

The table shows my use-case.

```
Instance  | Value (key:Purpose)     | Outcome
----------+-------------------------+------------
InstanceA | Going                   | Filter
InstanceB | Shopping,Going          | Filter
InstanceC | Going,Shoping           | Filter
InstanceD | Shopping,Going,Chatting | Filter
InstanceE | GoingGreat              | DONT Filter
InstanceF | NotGoing                | DONT Filter
```

So I want to somehow use wildcard in the ec2-describe-instances command so that I get the expected outcome.

Comment: you can run `ec2-describe-instances ... |grep -v KEYWORD` to exclude the recodes from output

Comment: Thanks for the comment, however I want to use the -filters available with AWS commands and use wildcards in them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is an example of how to filter the output of `ec2-describe-instances` based on the value of a tag:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].[InstanceId]' --filters "Name=platform,Values=windows" --output text
```

This example shows the Instance ID for all EC2 instance with the "platform" tag set to a value of "windows".

Wildcards are also permitted in the Values parameter (eg `Name=platform,Values=win*`).

Comment: Thanks a lot John,
I am trying something like:
aws_cmd ec2-describe-instances --region $region --filter tag:Platform=$platform_id

The platform_id is a parameter coming from somewhere else...Apart from (*) wildcard I wasnt able to use any other wildcard with $platform_id.
Will your syntax allow me this?
I will also try it out.

Comment: You could do: Values=*$platform_id*

Comment: But this will fail in following case:
I want to get only instances with Purpose = Going
Now i pass this value in platform_id
If i do *$platform_id* I will get all the instances from the table, whereas I just need InstanceA,B,C and D filtered because only these have 'Going' as a full string and not a part of string.Hope i was able to put my question clearly.

Comment: Yep. In that case, try to use values that don't partially overlap. Otherwise, you'll have to do some post-processing to apply more detailed logic (eg "Going" but not "NotGoing").

Comment: Yup, thats what I have though about as a rescue.
However the ideal situation would be to have the tag values whatever I like.
Thanks anyway for your time and efforts.
Cheers!