# Wildcards on query for AWS cli for elbv2

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-elb

I'm trying to get the ARN of some LoadBalancer which I only know the prefix of the DNS name.

As an example, `aws elbv2 describe-load-balancers --query 'LoadBalancers[].DNSName[]'` will print me:

```
[
    "services-green-********.elb.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com",
    "services-blue-********.elb.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com"
]
```

Something like

```
aws elbv2 describe-load-balancers --query "LoadBalancers[?DNSName=='services-green-*']"
```

is not working because wildcards are not accepted and using filters like at [ec2 commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27719831/how-can-i-use-wildcards-in-aws-cli-ec2-commands) is not possible.

How can I get the ARN without falling back to using jq?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may try this;

```
aws elbv2 describe-load-balancers --query 'LoadBalancers[?contains(DNSName, `services-green-*`) == `true`][DNSName]'
```

You may remove the last `[DNSName]` if you want the full response. Or replace with `DNSName` with `LoadBalancerArn`;

```
aws elbv2 describe-load-balancers --query 'LoadBalancers[?contains(DNSName, `services-green-*`) == `true`][LoadBalancerArn]'
```

Just like `contains`, you can try `starts_with` if you don't want full wildcard but know how it starts.